# How to change MATLAB's default work folder?

Tags: 12.10, matlab

After installing MATLAB2012b and starting it, the folder `MATLAB` gets created under `~/Documents/`.

I want this `MATLAB` folder to be created in other directory, for example `~/Documents/workspace`.

What should I do?

Comment: `12.04` or `12.10`? Please remove the extra tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case i install matlab in  this directory `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a`
then you go to `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/local`

```
ls startup.m
```

if you can't find the startup.m you can create this file by yourself.

the file contain syntax like this :

```
cd /path/your/path/you/want/matlab_work
```

it's work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

According to source ([1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/add-remove-or-reorder-folders-on-the-search-path.html)) you need to change the folders in the "search path" and for Linux Ubuntu I did the following (**tested on** `R2014a`, `R2014b`, `R2015a-prerelease`):

[This link shows you in pictures what is outlined below.](https://plus.google.com/photos/109580553763673889056/albums/6094384765266899633)
(Don't have enough rep to put everything here...)

**1.** Open Matlab and go to "Set Path"

**2.** Remove

```
`~/Documents/MATLAB`
```

**3.** Click `Add Folder...` button and select or make the folder you want to be searched by Matlab

**4.** Save the new `pathdef.m` somewhere that you are priviliged to save things in so I chose `~/Documents` to make things easy

**5.** Replace the current `pathdef.m` found in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R20xxx/toolbox/local/pathdef.m` (xxx= your version, mine was R2014b)

**6.** Open `Terminal` and type:

`sudo cp ~/Documents/pathdef.m /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/toolbox/local/pathdef.m`

**7.** Open `Matlab` and click the gear and go to General (`Preferences > General`) then set your new folder as the start location for every time you open `Matlab`

**8.** Delete `~/Documents/pathdef.m` file because you don't need it and will confuse you later.